# Android - ActivityUnitTestCase - Tests Always Pass

Tags: android, testing, android-studio

I am using Android Studio to try and test my activity.  Here is the basic code:

```
public class MyActivityTest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<MyActivity> {
    public MyActivityTest() {
        super(MyActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }

    @SmallTest
    public void testSomething() {
        Assert.assertNotNull("something is null", null);
    }
}
```

I would expect that this test case fails.  Everything I try passes though.  This seems like a strange question, but how can I make my test case fail?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working, sort of.  I found this on a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/issues/detail?id=121):

> We are in the process of deprecating ActivityUnitTestCase. We recommend to move business logic to a separate class and unit test it with gradle unit test support (mockable android.jar).

So I extended ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 instead and ran the test as an Instrumentation Test rather than a Unit Test.  That worked.  Here is basically what I have now:

```
public class MyActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivity> {
    public MyActivityTest() {
        super(MyActivity.class);
    }

    public void testSomething() throws Exception {
        //test goes here

        Assert.assertEquals(message, expectedObject, actualObject);
    }
}
```

I'm still not sure why I was seeing the behavior I was earlier, but at least I can test now.  Here is a screenshot of my Test Build Configuration:

[image]

Comment: This is not the answer! Instrumentation test requires device/emulator and are slow then unit test. we should wait for a better option :)

Comment: As soon as a better answer arrives, I will mark it as the answer.  Whether it is slower or not, this was the ONLY way I could get the tests to run.